# Using SolAdmin/Solace to see which application is sending data to a specific Queue

Tags: consumer, solace, producer

I'm working on an node js application, called `ngdf-diversion-client`, that is running in AWS and is connecting to a **Solace** instance, that is also running in AWS.

I see that through the `ngdf-diversion-client` config file its receiving messages over the `ngdf/diversions` queue, and I can see that in the **SolAdmin**.

This image here shows the application `ngdf-diversion-client` listed in the **SolAdmin** tool:
[image]

This image shows `ngdf-diversion-client` being the owner (and in my case the recipient of data) on the `ngdf/diversions` queue:
[image]

But I cannot see who sends data to `ngdf-diversion-client` on the `ngdf/diversions` queue.

Does anyone know how I can see that information in **Solace** or **SolAdmin**?

I know with **ActiveMQ** when you select a Queue or Topic from the web console, you can see who are the `consumers` and `producers` so it was pretty easy seeing who sent and who received data over a queue or topic.

But with **Solace/SolAdmin** I don't see that.

Answer (score 0):

With Solace, publishers and subscribers are decoupled by design so there is no way to see which publishers have sent messages to a specific queue. If it is required that the publisher of a message is identifiable then you could implement an identifier in the message as it is published in the application.